# How do I obtain Intents for static shortcuts (quickcuts) of all installed apps at runtime?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-package-managers, android-shortcut, android-shortcutmanager

In Android 7.1, there are app shortcuts ("quickcuts") that can be defined as intents in a shortcuts.xml resources file that is then referenced in a meta-data tag of the app's AndroidManifest.xml file.  An Action Launcher application can then use the "static shortcut" intents to launch an app with a specific activity defined in the intent. From Java code executing at runtime, how would I obtain all such static shortcut intents defined in an arbitrary app's AndroidManifest.xml and shortcuts.xml resources file?

Comment: I've never worked directly with them, so I can't post code, but it uses the `LauncherApps` class. I can't find how to get one thou https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/LauncherApps.html

Comment: found it. You call `getSystemService(Context.LAUNCHER_APPS_SERVICE)` and query with `getShortcuts`.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to get the static shortcuts on your runtime code ?
Maybe you can refer to the code as below, I hope this can help u

```
ShortcutManager shortcutManager = getSystemService(ShortcutManager.class);
List<ShortcutInfo> infos=shortcutManager.getManifestShortcuts();
    for(ShortcutInfo info : infos){
        info.getId());
        info.getLongLabel());
    }
```